# Using Selenium to login to password protected page

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am atempting to reach the following url (it requires a login/password): 'https://kenpom.com/conf.php?c=ACC/'

However when I run the below code, it brings me to this url: 'https://kenpom.com/index.php'

```
from selenium import webdriver

user = ''
pw = ''

url = 'https://kenpom.com/conf.php?c=ACC/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(user)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(pw)
driver.find_element_by_name('submit').click()
```

Any idea on why I am not reaching my desired page?

Comment: maybe try this url:
https://kenpom.com/register.php?frompage=1

Comment: I'm afraid that links to the same page I have in my post

Comment: it might be the query string. try https://kenpom.com/register.php